# Query result not getting mapped to mybatis resultMap

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis, wildfly-8

I have a resultSet which looks like this:

```
    <resultMap type="User" id="userMap">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result property="userName" column="user_name" />
        <result property="enabled" column="enabled" />
        <result property="firstName" column="first_name" />
        <result property="lastName" column="last_name" />
        <result property="email" column="email" />
        <result property="password" column="user_password" />
        <result property="passwordSalt" column="user_password_salt" />
        <result property="lastLogin" column="last_login_time" />
        <result property="creationTime" column="creation_time" />
        <result property="lastEdit" column="last_edit_time" />
        <result property="validTill" column="valid_till" />

        <collection property="roles" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Role" column="id">
            <id property="id" column="role_id" />
            <result property="name" column="role_name" />
            <result property="description" column="role_description" />
        </collection>

    </resultMap>
```

The select query mapping to this resultSet is:

```
<select id="getWithRole" resultMap="userMap" parameterType="User">
    SELECT * FROM view_boss_user_role
    <trim prefix="WHERE" prefixOverrides="AND | OR ">
        <if test="id != null">id = #{id}</if>
        <if test="userName != null">AND user_name = #{userName}</if>
        <if test="firstName != null">AND first_name = #{firstName}</if>
        <if test="lastName != null">AND last_name = #{lastName}</if>
        <if test="email != null">AND email = #{email}</if>
    </trim>
</select>
```

And the view query is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.view_boss_user_role(
    id,
    user_name,
    enabled,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    user_password,
    user_password_salt,
    last_login_time,
    creation_time,
    last_edit_time,
    valid_till,
    role_id,
    role_name,
    role_description)
AS
  SELECT bu.id,
         bu.user_name,
         bu.enabled,
         bu.first_name,
         bu.last_name,
         bu.email,
         bu.user_password,
         bu.user_password_salt,
         bu.last_login_time,
         bu.creation_time,
         bu.last_edit_time,
         bu.valid_till,
         br.id AS role_id,
         br.name AS role_name,
         br.description AS role_description
  FROM boss_user bu
       LEFT JOIN boss_role_user_map ru ON ru.user_id = bu.id
       LEFT JOIN boss_role br ON ru.role_id = br.id;
```

Which produces result similar to:

```
"id"    "user_name" "enabled"   "first_name"    "last_name" "email" "user_password" "user_password_salt"    "last_login_time"   "creation_time" "last_edit_time"    "valid_till"    "role_id"   "role_name" "role_description" 
"1" "admin" "True"  "Admin" "User"  "adminuser@gmail.com"   "SEli9hsMTTxGgjrlCz48+5w1CaMnUe/8xJJ0enOZ2ag="  "mBPa0wNPjvnGK3gzDMOHOg=="  "28-05-2017"    "28-05-2017"    "28-05-2017"    "31-05-2018"    "1" "ADMIN" "Administrator user"
```

But, when I try to get the roles list from this resultmap, it shows it as blank. I don't know what am I doing wrong. The documentation is either not apt to distinguish this case of collection tag or I'm just not getting it right.

For some reasons, I cannot make a single change to resultMap definition but can change the query. And it is guaranteed that the resultMap definition is correct.

Need an expert guidance

Comment: try including notNullColumn property on your <collection...>

Comment: @want2learn nopes. Didn't work

Comment: What does your `select` statement look like? It's necessary for analyzing.

Comment: @GeminiKeith Edited the question with query

Comment: Sorry, I mean the `<select>` tag not only the body of this select statement.

Comment: @GeminiKeith Done. Updated the question content

Comment: Try to enable debugging logging level to see the exact SQL statement and make sure the statement is what you want. Afterwards, you can debug into you application to find out the exactly objects returned in this statement.